# Official BIND9 Windows binaries - host.exe, dig.exe - don't do anything

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, bind, host, dig

I have downloaded the [official BIND 9 Windows binaries from ISC](https://www.isc.org/downloads/). They don't do anything:

```
$ .\host.exe google.com
$ (no output)
```

Same with `dig`. How do I make `host`, `dig` etc work on Windows?

Comment: In my experience it just works. Can you show more details of what happens?

Comment: Thanks @HåkanLindqvist It just returns to the prompt immediately. Even running `host -V` doesn't do anything. But it looks like it just needs the installer ran (which seems to do more than just move the files into place).

Comment: Downvoter - care to explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Simply unzipping the file won't work as various runtimes need to be installed. There's an installer inside the `.zip` called `BINDinstall.exe` - run that as Administrator and select **Tools Only**.

[image]

```
C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin $ .\host.exe -t MX certsimple.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

certsimple.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
certsimple.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
certsimple.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
certsimple.com mail is handled by 10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
certsimple.com mail is handled by 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Comment: Iirc just unzipping the file also works assuming you keep all the dependencies around (the dlls in that same dir) and have the needed vcredist version already installed. But yes, running the installer is clearly the intended way of using it.

Comment: Yeah @HåkanLindqvist you're right - it seems to work now with just the unzipped files. I think running the installer must have added some DLL etc that I didn't have before.